# CMake target_link_libraries public inheritance

Tags: cmake, public, target-link-libraries

I am educating myself on a [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/epezent/implot_demos/blob/4f3d91a85a6edd157dd98640e6b4eb99ecba956e/CMakeLists.txt#L81) of `implot` library. The `imgui` library, which is a library on which `implot` is based, declares the link libraries to be of type `PUBLIC`, as shown below.

```
# ...

add_library(imgui ${IMGUI_HEADERS} ${IMGUI_SRC})
if(MSVC)
  target_compile_options(imgui PRIVATE /W4 /WX /arch:AVX2 /fp:fast)
endif()
target_link_libraries(imgui PUBLIC glfw glad OpenGL::GL imm32)
target_compile_definitions(imgui PRIVATE IMGUI_DLL_EXPORT)

# ...

add_library(implot ${IMPLOT_HEADERS} ${IMPLOT_SRC})
target_link_libraries(implot PUBLIC imgui)
target_compile_definitions(implot PUBLIC IMPLOT_DEBUG IMPLOT_DLL_EXPORT IMPLOT_BACKEND_ENABLE_OPENGL3 IMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_LOADER_GLAD)
set_property(TARGET implot PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
if(MSVC)
  target_compile_options(implot PRIVATE /W4 /WX /arch:AVX2 /fp:fast /permissive-) 
else()
  target_compile_options(implot PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -mavx2 -Ofast)
endif()
```

Since `imgui` is `PUBLIC`ly linked against `glfw`, `glad`, `OpenGL::GL`, `imm32`, does it mean that `implot` and whoever that uses `implot` will also be `PUBLIC`ly linked against `glfw`, `glad`, `OpenGL::GL`, `imm32`?

Is the reason behind this because of `imgui` being a shared library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since imgui is PUBLICly linked against glfw, glad, OpenGL::GL, imm32, does it mean that implot and whoever that uses implot will also be PUBLICly linked against glfw, glad, OpenGL::GL, imm32?

Yes, it is. More details could be found in the official documentation in the section [Build Specification and Usage Requirements](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-specification-and-usage-requirements).

> Is the reason behind this because of imgui being a shared library?

Yes, it is. Since [`add_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#id2) does not have any `SHARED` or `STATIC` named parameter, a user may decide to build it statically by providing [`-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html) [`cmake(1)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#generate-a-project-buildsystem) parameter. So to link with it, a linker needs all the dependencies list. And this is a good practice to give him a choice on how to build your project ;-)